# A week old MS Teams invoke action button results in Invalid teamId and/or appId specified message

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm developing a Teams bot app that generates a thumbnail card (application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail) via unfurl or search extension. This card contains 3 buttons from which one of them invokes a task. Everything was working as expected for a while but then I noticed that if I click on that button on a card that's been posted more than a week ago, nothing happens, my server does not receive any request from MS Teams. Actually in the Teams web app you can see an error log in the JS console saying:

> AppsService: getInstalledAppForTeam - Invalid teamId and/or appId
> specified

If I post a new card from the same app (same app version without updating it), the button works again, but only for a week or so.

This is the JSON definition of that invoke button I use:

```
{
    "type": "invoke",
    "title": "Invoke task",
    "value": {
        "type": "task/fetch",
        "someObjectId": "123",
        "command": "myCommand"
    }
}
```

Not sure if I miss anything there but according to doc it does not seem like that.

Is there some defined period after which the invoke buttons are "retired"?

The app is installed via Teams Admin Center https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-apps

Answer (score 0):

I've not looked into this scenario, so I can't say *100%* for sure what's going on, but what I suspect is this: Your App Id/App Password are important because they're being used to secure the payload in some way, and that process might have a time limit to ensure stale messages aren't resent (i.e. replayed by an invalid party), or something like that. As a result, it's not that the app id is *per se* expired, but rather that the message somehow is. Again, just a theory...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem I've described appears to be inconsistent as is the whole MS Teams API behavior. Right now, for some instances it works fine even on a messages that are few months old.